# How to add 'loanPaid' every month

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing a problem where every time I refresh my page, the loan paid will increase by 500. I understand that my logic is wrong, after 1 month from the loan application date, the 'loanPaid' will increase by 500 but what I want to happen is every next month it will increase by $500. If anyone who can help me with the logic. I would appreciate it. I was thinking of using some loop but not sure which one and how. I'm a freshman student only so please pardon my coding style. Thank you

---

```
public class LoanDAL
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oakhorizons"].ToString();
    public LoanDAL()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public DataTable getAllLoanInfoDT()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = conn;
            // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT purchaseDate FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE (custID LIKE 'OH00002') AND (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan')";
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", "OH00002");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanType", "Personal Loan");
            conn.Open();
            string custID = "OH00002";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd2;
            da.Fill(dt);
            int iMonthNo = int.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString());
            DateTime dtDate = new DateTime(2000, iMonthNo, 1);
            double dMonthNow = Double.Parse(dtDate.ToString("MM"));
            LoanTableAdapters.LoanPortfolioTableAdapter loanAdapter = new LoanPortfolioTableAdapter();
            string LoanDate = loanAdapter.RetrieveData(custID.ToString()).ToString();
            string month = dt.ToString();

            double dLoanDate = Double.Parse(LoanDate.Substring(3, 2));

            if (dMonthNow > dLoanDate)
            {
                String sql = "UPDATE LoanPortfolio SET loanPaid = loanPaid + 500";
                sql += "WHERE (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan') AND (custID LIKE 'OH00002')";
                cmd2.Connection = conn;
                cmd2.CommandText = sql;

                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            conn.Close();
}
}
```

After edit:

```
 public DataTable getAllLoanInfoDT()
{ 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = conn;
        // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT loanUpdateDate FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE (custID LIKE 'OH00002') AND (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan')"; 
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", "OH00002");
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanType", "Personal Loan");
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        DateTime loanUpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader);
        DateTime currDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - loanUpdateDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - loanUpdateDate.Month) * 500;
        if (loanToBeAdded > 0)
        {
            String sql = "UPDATE LoanPortfolio SET loanPaid = loanPaid + " + loanToBeAdded.ToString() + ", loanUpdateDate = " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            sql += " WHERE (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan') AND (custID LIKE 'OH00002')";

            //Execute the above query here
        }
        conn.Close();

        using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM LoanPortfolio where custID like 'OH00002'", conn))
        {
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            dAd.Fill(dTable);
            return dTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really get what you are doing in your code. Especially why you generate an SqlDataAdapter, fill a DataTable and just use it to convert the DataTable into a string, which will result in the types name !?

Comment: Sorry sir. I'm still new to this. I would appreciate if u could help what should be the proper way of retrieving data in this kind of situation

Comment: Could you describe what exactly you want to do in the `getAllLoanInfo` method

Comment: I'm doing a project about retrieving some loan information. Such as loan amount, loan date(day it was applied), duration,interest rate, loan paid and type. Those are what I want to retrieve from getAllLoanInfo. However, I also want it to update that every month, loan paid will increase and decrease the total amount of loan remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a lot of unnecessary things, some important checks missing and some performance inhibiting mistakes also in your code but I will not point them out here since you are a freshman and you will learn gradually.

The solution to your problem should be the following

1. Firstly create a new column in your "LoanPortfolio" table namely "LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate". The type should be Date for this column. This will store the date when you last added $500 to "loanPaid" column.
2. Set this column same as "purchaseDate" when you first add a row in your "LoanPortfolio" table. So initially "purchaseDate" and "LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate" will be same.
3. Fetch only "LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate" instead of "purchaseDate" as

   ```
       cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate FROM LoanPortfolio WHERE (custID LIKE 'OH00002') AND (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan')";
   ```
4. Assuming that there will be just 1 record fetched from the above query, The following code should add $500 to "loadPaid" column once every month

   ```
       //Fetch "LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate" here

       //This will be "LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate" coming from database i.e. dt[0][0].ToString(). Hard-coded here for simplicity
       string strLastUpdatedLoanPaidDate = "07/29/2013";

       DateTime lastUpdatedLoanPaidDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strLastUpdatedLoanPaidDate);
       DateTime currDateTime = DateTime.Now;

       //This will make sure that all the previous purchases are also handled and not just previous month's
       //This is important when you are implementing new logic on existing data
       int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - lastUpdatedLoanPaidDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - lastUpdatedLoanPaidDate.Month) * 500;

       //If loadToBeAdded is zero then need not update database
       if (loanToBeAdded > 0)
       {
           String sql = "UPDATE LoanPortfolio SET loanPaid = loanPaid + " + loanToBeAdded.ToString() + ", LastUpdatedLoanPaidDate = " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
           sql += " WHERE (loanType LIKE 'Personal Loan') AND (custID LIKE 'OH00002')";

           //Execute the above query here
       }
   ```

There might be some things which I am missing depending upon your requirement. Also the update statement might need a tweak as I have not tested it but overall this should do the trick.

Hope this helped.

Regards,

Samar

Comment: I've tried your codes and I got this problem "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'." Thanks for your answer it's very detailed.=)

Comment: Can u help me check whether I declared it correctly from the after edit of my work?

Comment: You cannot convert the reader directly to DateTime. You would need a while loop there as SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime loanUpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]); break;
            }

Comment: Ok. Then I did. but the calculation u gave me    "int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - loanUpdateDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - loanUpdateDate.Month) * 500;" How am I gonna declare the 'loanUpdateDate' again?. Please pardon me as I really am new to this.

Comment: Declare or Update? If you meant "update", then please see my answer above. Inside the if condition there is an update statement. That statement is updating the "loanPaid" as well as "loanUpdateDate" column for the particular custID.

Comment: I meant the loanToBeAdded calculation. It says  the name 'loanUpdateDate' does not exist in the current context. So how will i solve that?

Comment: You need to declare the variable "loanUpdateDate" outside the while block. So your code should be DateTime loanUpdateDate; SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); while (reader.Read()) { loanUpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]); break; }

Comment: I've tried that before and I got this error "A local variable name 'loanUpdateDate' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning meaning to 'loanUpdateDate', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. Inside the while statement "loanUpdateDate" does not contain "DateTime" written behind it.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see. thanks but I dont know why I'm still getting this funny error "Use of unassigned local variable 'loanUpdateDate' on the "int loanToBeAdded = (((currDateTime.Year - loanUpdateDate.Year) * 12) + currDateTime.Month - loanUpdateDate.Month) * 500;" part.

Comment: When you declare the variable just assign it to DateTime.Now. So your declaration will be DateTime loanUpdateDate = DateTime.Now; This variable is any case going to get reassigned inside while loop so this assignment would affect anything. Also please mark as answered (tick mark) to the post which best answered your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also indicate in your table when you increased the loan for the last time and check this value, too. You could insert a new column `lastLoanIncrease` in the table `LoanPortFolio`   as `char(6)` and save the month and year, when you increased it. Then before increasing again check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop.

Your issue is in your conditional `if`

```
//DateTime loanDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 18);
DateTime loanDueDate = Foo.GetLoanDueDate(loanId);

int loanDueMonth = loanDueDate.Month;
int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

if (currentMonth > loanDueMonth)
    {
        // update db
        loanDate.AddMonths(1);
        Foo.UpdateLoanDueDate(loanId, loanDate); // increase loan due date for next month so that the conditional is true next month.
    }
```

Comment: So how do I retrieve my 'purchaseDate' to compare with the date now? I don't get the line "DateTime loanDueDate = Foo.GetLoanDueDate(loanId);". And What is 'Foo'?. Sorry I'm still a beginner for this.

Comment: You store it and retrieve it from the database. Foo is an example class that gets and sets your loan due date, you have to create it. You have to keep track of when the loan is due to be paid.

Comment: So I need to make another class called 'Foo'?. I'm quite confused sir. I'm still new to this.